# Editable metro calendar for winrt?

Tags: c#, calendar, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I did a business app on the Windows Phone 8 platform (XAML, C#),
and used the microsoft.phone.toolkit to make an awesome calendar.

Now I need to rewrite the app for the Surface (winrt) and there is no easy way to this as far as I have searched, I got one perfectly fine calendar, [Here](http://nuget.org/packages/Win8Controls/), but I can't edit it to look like the rest of my metro app, so I would like any advice or links to classes I can use to get a calendar into my app? I don't have the time to create my own from scratch... But will do it if I can get a very good tutorial on where to start with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, both of you guys point to exact same project I wrote sometime ago.  If you want to change the look of the calendar, just create your own style that replaces the one that ships with nuget.  The link from above does show a style that ships with it.  You can either edit that one or (better) create your own and inject it through a resource dictionary.  if you download project from CodePlex, it should show you how to replace default styles.
Thanks.

Comment: that is what i figured,  so that is what i did, thanks for the clarity!